# Possible to catch HTTP Post request from browser as plain text?

Tags: html, firefox, post

I know you can catch POST requests and inspect the contents with Firebug, HTTPFox and Tamper Data etc..  But how can I just view the request as plain text?

Edit:  Ok what I mean is that I want to see the HTTP request (headers and all) as text that I can just copy and paste into notepad for instance.  As I understand it HTTP is a text based protocol.  I want to view the request as text from start to finish including mime parts.

Comment: Do you mean view the raw HTTP packet? Firebug and similar tools often have a way to view the raw packets. If you really want to see what's being sent over the wire, try [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Yes I have tried wireshark and others however I would like to see the HTTP request as plain text that I can copy into notepad.

Comment: You can do that with Wireshark: [follow TCP stream](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowTCPSection.html).

Comment: @tjameson Maybe I'm doing something wrong but it's not showing me the actual POST request when I click on follow TCP stream.  It shows a GET request.  I am behind a proxy as well.